# What are the specific user agent string for different browser of iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, firefox, browser, user-agent

What are the specific user agent string for different browser of iOS?

Example for chrome is,

"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 5_1_1 like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/534.46.0 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/19.0.1084.60 Mobile/9B206 Safari/7534.48.3"

So what are the specific user agent for the following browser?

1) Firefox
2) Opera
3) Atomic
4) Mercury
5) Dolphin
6) Puffin
7) Ucbrowser

Answer (score 0):

Check this site, it has a very long list of user agent strings for each browser http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php

Comment: I don't see any browser that i have mentioned.